# Getting a libprotobuf error message when importing storage module of google.cloud

Tags: python, cloud, protocol-buffers

When I run `from google.cloud import storage` in Python, I receive the following error:

`ImportError: libprotobuf.so.23.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this error message by downgrading my protobuf library, as suggested in [this thread](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/10051#issuecomment-1138392640). Running `conda install protobuf=3.20.1` in my terminal successfully downgraded both protobuf and libprotobuf, and now I can import the storage module from google.cloud without any issues.